# UI MultiSelect : pass class from option to rendered li

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-multiselect

The title is quite explicit. Some options in my `<select>` have a certain class (or data) and i want to see those classes in ui multiselect rendered options which are `<li>` with an input and a span in them. Then I will be able to style those options differently.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an improved version of the plugin on his gitub page, here is the plugin file : https://github.com/nils-a/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/blob/162867ffe2bc216d09078b69a2f15ffa4e8d5e92/src/jquery.multiselect.js

Does the job.